# How to match up the currently clicked item with mongodb document array object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

Say I had a mongodb document like the one in the picture. Each favorites object is displayed in a "gallery" with a trash button. How would I, onclick of the trash button, delete the currently clicked object from favorites array? I'm using node.js and ejs.[Mongodb document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4kxp.jpg)

Before I've been able to delete documents with ids on frontend using data-sets. Now I'm not really sure how I would Grab that item on the frontend and tell nodejs to delete that specific object from the favorite array

Comment: Each `favorite` should have an unique id; that'd make this that much easier...

Comment: I was following the one to few model on this site: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-schema-design-best-practices/ . I agree using ids is a lot easier. I'm a beginner so I'm just trying to figure out the correct way to setup my model.

Answer (score 0):

The `$pull` operator will remove element from array. In your case:

```
User.updateOne(
  { _id: 'your id here' },
  // Remove all element that has image equal to 'my-images\droneredcopy.jpg'
  { $pull: { favorites: { image: 'my-images\droneredcopy.jpg' } } } 
)
```

You can find the documentation here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/